# Where to put .tmLanguage in sublime text 3?

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax, highlighting, sublimetext3

I'm having trouble with Ruby syntax highlighting in combination with RegExp.

Someone suggested that I update my Ruby.tmLanguage file with some additional code.

Problem is, I can't locate this file on my computer. Inside sublime_text_3/Packages I only see .sublime-package files, which I can't properly open with sublime text; it only shows numbers.

Do I have to create this file myself, and if so, where?

Or does this work differently in sublime text 3 (as opposed to 2, which was probably the latest version when this solution got posted).

reference to additional Ruby.tmLanguage code: https://gist.github.com/elgalu/3921521

Comment: I encountered similar issue. You can find answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385550/syntax-highlight-tmlanguage-in-sublime-text-3-for-packages/20409424#20409424) thread.

Answer (score 7):

Those .sublime-package files are actually zip files in disguise. The default Ruby.tmLanguage file can be extracted from Ruby.sublime-package. Open it with some sort of archive manager. Copy and rename the extension to .zip if you have to.

Once you've made the changes in Ruby.tmLanguage, the modified file goes somewhere in your packages folder (I can't remember exactly where), which you can open from ST by going to Preferences > Browse Packages.

Comment: Note: I've tried uncompressing `.tmLanguage` files and run into an endless loop of `.cpgz` and `.zip` expansions. See: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1446784

Comment: @DavidJames the `.tmLanguage` files are just text files and can be opened by most any text editor (particularly in Sublime Text itself). It's the `.sublime-package` files that are compressed/zipfiles. Change the file's extension to end in .zip instead (I tend to leave the sublime-package part so I recall what it is, eg `Ruby.sublime-package.zip`) and then it'll uncompress as expected.