# Fix Sublime Text 3 Clojure Syntax Highlighting (Regexes especially)

Tags: clojure, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3's Clojure syntax highlighting often breaks on/after regular expressions. I see that Anthony Grimes noticed this on the Sublime Text Forum: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/82983-clojure-regexes-are-not-parsed-properly/

This answer was suggested:

> Inside `Clojure.tmLanguage` try changing
>
> `<string>source.regexp.oniguruma</string>`
>
> to
>
> `<string>#string_escape</string>`

But where is `Clojure.tmLanguage`? After I make the change, do I just save it in place? (See [Where to put .tmLanguage in sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790062/where-to-put-tmlanguage-in-sublime-text-3))

I see have this in my Sublime Text 3 directory:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── Cache
├── Index
├── Installed\ Packages
├── Local
└── Packages
```

Inside `Cache` I see `Clojure/Clojure.tmLanguage.cache` but that probably isn't right.

Update: I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.

Update: I'm looking over  [Where are .tmLanguage files stored for ST3](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10933)

Update: There are other Clojure syntax issues detailed here, too: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14077

Update: I've tried uncompressing the `Clojure.tmLanguage.cache` file by renaming it to `Clojure.tmLanguage.zip` first. That was bizarre; I get an alternating and endless loop of `.cpgz` and `.zip` files as I try to uncompress them. See: discussions.apple.com/thread/1446784

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo Mac OS X (updated above). Won't the answer be OS independent? By that I mean this -- the way I understand it, ST3 may put the app root in different places, but things hook together similarly, right?

Comment: no, the default packages are in different locations depending on OS, but the answer I'm composing now gets around that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to be changing items in the default packages in Sublime Text 3, I **highly** recommend installing [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) by @skuroda. It allows you to open, view, edit, and extract packages from their default storage location (which varies by operating system) and place them in `Packages/PackageName`, overriding the default.

Once you've installed the plugin, go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> PackageResourceViewer -> Settings - User` and paste in the following:

```json
{
    "single_command": false
}
```

This just gives you some extra options in the Command Palette. Next, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type in `prv` to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options. Select `Edit Package Resource` and navigate to `Clojure -> Clojure.tmLanguage`. Do your search and replace, and save the file, which will now be located in `Packages/Clojure/Clojure.tmLanguage` in case you need to edit it again - you'll be able to open it like a normal file.

To answer the original question, on OS X the pristine `.sublime-package` files are located in `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages`. However, these files should never be modified directly, as **a)** you could easily break something, and **b)** they are overwritten upon upgrade, so any changes would be lost.

Good luck!

---

BTW, a little plug if you're using Clojure and would like some better syntax highlighting: I'm the maintainer of the [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), and I just released a new version that includes more specific support for Clojure, aside from what was already there. My aim for the color scheme is to make as many languages as possible look as good as possible, taking advantage of as many scopes as I can in the `.tmLanguage` definition file. I just recently started learning Clojure, and the language definition is fairly rich, so there are a lot of opportunities for context-specific highlighting. Check it out, and please [let me know](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) what you think!

Comment: Awesome! I just edited `Clojure.tmLanguage` using this method. I see that `PackageResourceViewer` dropped a safe copy for me to modify in my `TM3-ROOT/Packages/Clojure` directory.

Comment: glad I could help! See my edit regarding my Neon color scheme that I just recently updated for Clojure - it's much better than any of the Sublime defaults :)